# Why motion sensors doesn't trigger?

Tags: android

I'm trying to test my motion sensors (on Galaxy S7) with the following code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private SensorManager sensorManager;
        private Sensor sensorGRAVITY;
        private Sensor sensorACCELEROMETER;
        private TriggerEventListener triggerEventListenerGRAVITY;
        private TriggerEventListener triggerEventListenerACCELEROMETER;



        private void initManagers() {
            sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

            // --- TYPE_GRAVITY
            sensorGRAVITY = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
            triggerEventListenerGRAVITY = new TriggerEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTrigger(TriggerEvent event) {
                    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    textView.setText("[0] = " + String.valueOf(event.values[0]) + " [1] = " + String.valueOf(event.values[1]));
                }
            };
            sensorManager.requestTriggerSensor(triggerEventListenerGRAVITY, sensorGRAVITY);

            // --- TYPE_ACCELEROMETER
            sensorACCELEROMETER = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            triggerEventListenerACCELEROMETER = new TriggerEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTrigger(TriggerEvent event) {
                    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    textView.setText("[0] = " + String.valueOf(event.values[0]) + " [1] = " + String.valueOf(event.values[1]));
                }
            };
            sensorManager.requestTriggerSensor(triggerEventListenerACCELEROMETER, sensorACCELEROMETER);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            initManagers();

        }


    }
```

but it seems that no trigger is showing.
I have tried to talk and move my Galaxy for several seconds and the textview1 and textview2 doesn't changed.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your TriggerEventListener() outside th initmanagers() method. 
private void initManagers() {

```
       sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

            // --- TYPE_GRAVITY
            sensorGRAVITY = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
            triggerEventListenerGRAVITY = new TriggerEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTrigger(TriggerEvent event) {
                    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    textView.setText("[0] = " + String.valueOf(event.values[0]) + " [1] = " + String.valueOf(event.values[1]));
                }
            };
            sensorManager.requestTriggerSensor(triggerEventListenerGRAVITY, sensorGRAVITY);

            // --- TYPE_ACCELEROMETER
            sensorACCELEROMETER = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

            sensorManager.requestTriggerSensor(triggerEventListenerACCELEROMETER, sensorACCELEROMETER);
        }
triggerEventListenerACCELEROMETER = new TriggerEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTrigger(TriggerEvent event) {
                    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    textView.setText("[0] = " + String.valueOf(event.values[0]) + " [1] = " + String.valueOf(event.values[1]));
                }
            };
```